# nightwatchjs, run same test on multiple pages

Tags: nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

I have written some tests for my homepage but the tests are very generic, like footer, header checking.

My test structure is like:

```
const footerCheck = function(browser){ 
    browser.url("example.com");
    browser.verify.elementPresent(".footer-top", "Footer-top is present.")
    browser.verify.elementPresent(".footer-middle", "Legal notice bar is present")
    browser.verify.elementPresent(".footer-bottom", "Copyright bar is present")
    }

export.module = {
"Footer Check" : footerCheck
}
```

Lets say I have 100 pages. I would like to run `footerCheck` function run on all hundred pages.

URLs like example.com/page1 , example.com/page2 , example.com/page3...

Since all the tests are valid for other pages I would like to loop all pages  for the same test cases. Somehow could not get my head around it.

How is that possible, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide more sample code, your question is too general.

Comment: @BaoTran I have updated my code, hope it gives an idea.

Comment: I answered a similar question yesterday here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45988237/mocha-unable-to-run-with-nightwatch/46077141#46077141 . You can create dynamic tests if you use Mocha, cucumber works too but it adds another layer to your tests and if your team isn't all onboard with BDD and cucumber it will hurt your productivity in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

In my personal experience, the best way to do BDD is adding cucumber that uses [gherkin](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Gherkin) syntax. It is clearer and helps a lot to reduce redundant code if you know to use it well. There is a [Nightwatch npm plugin](https://github.com/mucsi96/nightwatch-cucumber) to add cucumber, once you have added it you have to create your .feature file like the following

```
Feature: Check elements are present
Scenario Outline:
Given the user enters on a <page>
Then .footer-top, .footer-middle and .footer-bottom class should be enabled

Examples:
|page|
|page.com/page1|
|page.com/page2|
|page.com/page3|
```

And your step definitions (where you declare what will do each step) it automatically will run each step for each url provided in the examples (note the `<page>` flag that will be replaced on the example, first row is the name of the tag).

Take a look to the [examples](https://github.com/mucsi96/nightwatch-cucumber-example)