# Mocha unable to run with Nightwatch

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

I'm running mocha with nighwatch.js, selenium and chromedriver

I'm able to run with describe, and it, but I'm making a dynamic tests, so I need use the following way to invoke, but I'm unable to get mocha running this way with nightwatch

```
"use strict";

var nightwatch = require('nightwatch');

var Mocha = require('mocha');
var Test = Mocha.Test;
var Suite = Mocha.Suite;

var mocha = new Mocha();
var suite = Suite.create(mocha.suite, 'Search Box');

suite.addTest(new Test('I\'m a dynamic test', function (done) {
    var client = nightwatch.initClient({
        silent : true
    });
    var browser = client.api();
    browser.url(browser.launch_url);
    client.start(done);
}));

mocha.run();
```

Here's the error
Starting selenium server... started - PID:  122624

```
0 passing (0ms)

  Search Box
    1) I'm a dynamic test

There was an error while starting the test runner:

Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. ([object Object])
    at Nightwatch.<anonymous> (E:\gitwork\AAPT-SPZA\src\frontEnd\node_modules\nightwatch\lib\runner\clientmanager.js:66:1
    at HttpRequest.<anonymous> (E:\gitwork\AAPT-SPZA\src\frontEnd\node_modules\nightwatch\lib\index.js:501:10)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (E:\gitwork\AAPT-SPZA\src\frontEnd\node_modules\nightwatch\lib\http\request.js:174:12)
```

How to fix this and get Mocha running with Nightwatch?

Comment: Why not use the forked Mocha library specifically for Nightwatch? Dynamic tests in Nightwatch with Mocha are definitely possible if you follow the Nightwatch documentation.

Comment: @sonhu That's what I did, [doc](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide/#using-mocha) it doesn't seem to work. Could you please post your working dynamic tests with Mocha on Nightwatch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a format similar to the below to achieve dynamic tests in Nightwatch.js using Mocha. The below example isn't a real test so don't try to run it but it should give you a good idea of how to go about it. The test results all show up as different tests with different assertions. The conf file should look like it does normally besides setting mocha as the test runner.

```
const async = require('async');
const languages = [{
    name: 'english',
    currency: '$'
    }, {
    name: 'german',
    currency: '€'
}]; 
describe('An example test', () => {
   async.each(languages, function (language) {
    it(`When I click the ${language.name} link my page should be in ${language.name}`, (browser) => {
        browser.url('http://www.google.com');
        homePage.click(`@${language.name}Link`);
        homePage.expect.element('#sub-title').text.to.equal(`Your language is ${language.name}`);
    });
   });
})
```

**Note:** It's extremely important to run an async loop using something like the async library, nightwatch won't run a normal for each asynchronously for you and it will result in a lot of errors.

Comment: Thanks, do you know why there's error message on my code? Actually I want the input to be dynamic too. First fetch the input, instead of hard-coding, and then use fetched input to create test cases.

Comment: I don't know but the way you are using mocha with Nightwatch might be pushing it. Nightwatch is a very opinionated framework and the further you deviate from how the documentation is laid out the more you are likely to run into these types of errors that may involve you needing to fork Nightwatch to get it working.

Comment: In terms of the dynamic input you can use a npm library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/urllib-sync I would normally do it through nightwatch globals but it's really hard for me to give you an answer based on the way you are using mocha. The easy way out is urllib-sync.